# Как скрыть ссылку по таймеру

Tags: javascript, php

Как то я добился чтоб открыть ссылку по таймеру а как типер сделать что по истичению другого времени скрыть ее обратно

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title></title>

    </head>
    <body >

    <?php
    //error_reporting (0);
    ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
      //date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Kiev');//timzone

    /**  time_table.dat
    1|text|link|12|10|2018|10:00:00|09:55:00|10:30:00|  
    2|text|link|12|10|2018|21:00:00|20:55:00|21:30:00|  
    3|text|link|12|10|2018|22:00:00|21:55:00|22:30:00| 
    */
      date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Kiev');//timzone


        $data =  file("time_table.dat");

      foreach($data as $rows) {

        $elem = explode("|", $rows);
        if (!strripos($rows, "|")) continue;

    echo'<table border="1" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="300">

      <tr>
        <td valign="top" align="center"  width="150">
            '.$elem[3].'/'.$elem[4].'/'.$elem[5].'-'.$elem[6].'<br>
        '.$elem[1].'
        </td>
        <td valign="top" align="center"  width="150">
    <script type="text/javascript">

    /////////////////////////
    timedown("'.$elem[3].','.$elem[4].','.$elem[5].','.$elem[7].'","link_'.$elem[0].'");
    //var countDownDate = new Date("<?=$elem[3].','.$elem[4].','.$elem[5].','.$elem[8];?>");// до закрытия ссылки 
    function timedown(ti,id){

    var countDownDate = new Date(ti).getTime();

    var x = setInterval(function() {

        var now = new Date().getTime();

        var distance = countDownDate - now;

        var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = "до входа<br>"+(days!=0 ? days + ":" : "") + (hours!= 0 ? hours + ":" : "") + (minutes != 0 ? minutes + ":" : "") + seconds + "<br><a href=\"#\">Неактивная</a>";

        if (distance < 0) {
            clearInterval(x);
            document.getElementById("link_'.$elem[0].'").innerHTML = "<a href=\"'.$elem[2].'\">Активная</a>";
        //window.location = "final.php" // по окончанию времени перейти на другу страницу

        }
    }, 1000);
    }

    /**  помогите прикрутить таймер до закрытия ссылки и спрятать ссылку обратно*/

    </script>       

    <span id="link_'.$elem[0].'"></span>


        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>';
      }

    ?>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: "Кол, а Кол, фкалю ф тибя укол."

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById("link_'.$elem[0].'").innerHTML = "<a href=\"'.$elem[2].'\">Активная</a>";
setTimeout(function(){
  document.getElementById("link_'.$elem[0].'").innerHTML = "";
}, 2000);
```

Comment: спасибо что ответили но чтоб спрятать ссылку нужно взять значение из $elem[8] както

Comment: @ПетроБойко о какой ссылке идет речь?

Comment: <a href=\"'.$elem[2].'\">Активная</a> обратно спрятать по таймеру а показать  <a href=\"#\">Неактивная</a>